# Strict conditional filtering type (Typescript)

Tags: typescript, type-inference, conditional-types

I am trying to create strict filtering interface:

```
type Filter<I, O extends I = I> = (value: I) => I extends O ? boolean : false
```

By writing this line I want to define a type constraint for a function which:

1. receives value of type `I`
2. returns `false` if value **is not** of expected type (`I extends O` is not `true`)
3. returns `true | false` if value **is** of expected type and matches filter

But Typescript ignores conditional return type:

```
type MessageA = { type: 'A' }
type MessageB = { type: 'B' }
type Message = MessageA | MessageB

const filter: Filter<Message, MessageA> = ({ type }) => type === 'A'
const inputMessage: Message = { type: 'B' }

if (filter(inputMessage)) {
  // the following line produces error
  const message: MessageA = inputMessage
  // because according to TS compiler
  // inputMessage is still `MessageA | MessageB`
}
```

Logically `filter(inputMessage)` MAY produce `true` if `inputMessage` is of type `MessageA`.

I'd like to understand *"is it achievable?"* and *"how to write it properly?"* if it is.

---

I am not restricted with version of typescript, currently latest (for the moment) Typescript 3.9.5 is installed. I am using VSCode 1.46, whether it makes any difference.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards

Comment: @IngoBürk i do not see relation of type guards to my question. can you please clarify what should i look at there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

You can try this:

```
type Filter<T, U extends T> = (candidate: T) => candidate is U;

const filter: Filter<Message, MessageA> = (message): message is MessageA => message.type === 'A'
```

But you still need to explicitly define the return type (`: message is MessageA`).

**Solution 2**

This one is more complex, but it makes your type guards (refinements) type-safe.

Create a factory for type guards like this:

```
namespace Refinement {
  class Hit<T> {
    constructor(readonly value: T) {}
  }

  class Miss {}

  type Result<T> = Hit<T> | Miss;

  export function hit<T> (value: T) {
    return new Hit(value);
  }

  export const miss = new Miss();

  export function create<T, U extends T>(refine: (candidate: T) => Result<U>): (candidate: T) => candidate is U {
    return (candidate): candidate is U => refine(candidate) instanceof Hit;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
declare const inputMessage: Message;

const filter = Refinement.create(
  (message: Message) => message.type === 'A'
    ? Refinement.hit(message)
    : Refinement.miss
)

if (filter(inputMessage)) {
  inputMessage; // MessageA
}
```

This approach is used by `fp-ts` for example.

Comment: this removes compilation error. but it does not enforce strictness. i still can say `message.type === 'B'` in same line and it will not even warn me

Comment: Gotcha. Updated my answer. It looks scary, but it's the only way that works.

Comment: oh! that's not concise as i expected... thanks a lot for pointing to `fp-ts`, i'll definitely take a look what's there. the code from second solution looks like monad, but very awkward one (and i'll need some time to understand how it works). i was hoping to avoid using classes. i somehow felt all the way that classes are just something wrong in JS. probably you can explain me why conditional type does not work? I would understand TS better after that. thanks!

Comment: Your intuition is correct! The `fp-ts` solution is using the `Option` monad to solve that problem. I remade it so that one doesn't need to bring `fp-ts` to solve such a simple task as creating a type guard. As for classes: you can use something else — what matters is that the value has to be boxed.

Comment: i decided to go with `type Filter<I, O extends I = I> = (input: I) => O extends I ? (O | undefined) : undefined` and filter `undefined`s in filter's client. i expect to have just one client and multiple implementation providers; so it appears to be more reasonable to have simpler implementation definitions rather than simplify its application.

Answer (score 0):

By using Array.flatMap you can filter value and also filter types, see:

```js
const values: Array<string | null> = ['asd', null, 'zxc', null]
const nonNullValues = values.flatMap(value => value ? [value] : []) // string[]
```